# Change @RequestMapping order

Tags: spring-mvc

I have two methods mapped with @GetMapping:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/**", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, params = "test")
public String getTest(@RequestParam("test") String test) {
          ...
}
```

```
@GetMapping(path = "/some/path", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getTest() {
          ...
}
```

Is it possible to request to endpoint `/some/path?test=string` be mapped 
to first method, and request to endpoint `some/path` be mapped to second method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you could use `!test` as the value of [`params`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--):

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/some/path", 
            params = "!test",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Quoting the [`params`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--) documentation:

> [...] Expressions can be negated by using the `!=` operator, as in `myParam!=myValue`. [...] Finally, `!myParam` style expressions indicate that the specified parameter is not supposed to be present in the request.