# Influencing order of RequestMapping processing

Tags: spring-boot, request-mapping

In short this is what I'm searching for: I want to create a RequestMapping that catches *all* URLs *except* a small list I don't want to catch.
The minimum to exclude is everything below `/webjars/`, I also would like to exclude other URLS like `/actuator/` and probably more.

**Background information**

We need to replace an old CMS which has literally thousands of different URLs. All URLs need to be detected and checked against a database and then the users shall be presented with a landing page, this landing page will then redirect the user to the new CMS target URL.
The logic that needs to be applied is too complicated for some Apache / nginx magic, therefore I wrote a Spring Boot application that can accomplish this.

I've created a `@RequestMapping(value = "**", method = RequestMethod.GET)` that catches all `GET` requests (these are the one I want to grab and react on) and a `@RequestMapping(value = "**")` for the other http verbs like `POST` and `DELETE` which I simply abort by sending a http error status code.
This works fine and the (simplified) code looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String catchAccepted(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("targetUrl", ua.deriveNewUrl(request));

    return "redirect";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "**")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> catchDenied(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT);
}
```

The page that gets displayed for all the `GET` requests is based on a Thymeleaf template which uses Bootstrap in order to do the layout job.
In order to include Bootstrap I use the `webjars-locator` and `org.webjars.bootstrap`, the resources are included by specifying `<script src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` in the `redirect.html` Thymeleaf template.

**Problem**

The problem is, that my `**` mapping on GET also gets applied to the `/webjars/...` call and instead of the desired js code I get whatever my redirect template returns.
I found no way to tell Spring Boot about the desired order.

*First*  I would like to have Spring Boot handle the `webjars` mapping, *then* my other mapping.

**Attempts so far**

I checked [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440991/how-do-i-set-priority-on-spring-mvc-mapping) posts on SO but they only work when I have access to the sourcecode where the mapping is made. And I don't have access to the webjars locator / see no point in changing it just to solve this issue.

I also tried to set up a "anything that is not related to webjars" mapping like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "^(?!webjars$|actuator$).*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

But this doesn't have the desired effect because the RequestMapping only seems to support ant-stlye paths, which doesn't support negations because Ant (in contrast to Spring Boot) has a field for includes and excludes: https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html

Negating the mapping seems only to be possible for params, not for the path: [Change @RequestMapping order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184022/change-requestmapping-order)

Comment: Had any luck with https://stackoverflow.com/q/1234298/5757893 ?

Comment: Did you try out produces/consumes in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping ? Maybe you can target only html sources and ignore others?

Comment: @mohkamfer as for your first suggestion: I would like to avoid "messing" with the Servlet setup directly and I would like to stick with the newstyle declarations and rather not resort to xml style. But this could be the final option if I don't find a different approach, thank you

Comment: @mohkamfer regarding your second suggestion: this can be a workaround but so far I am not completely sure which other mimetypes I need to support. I've seen `.svg` in the CMS for example, in order to go for your suggested approach I need more insight into the stuff stored inside the CMS

Answer (score 1):

I didn't yet find a way to influence the order if other mappings come from code I can not incluence.

But I found a way to configure "catch all *except* of ...":

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "", "/", "{url:(?!webjars$|actuator$).*}/**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

This configures three mappings. The first two are there to handle calls to the root of the webserver. The third configures a path pariable which I could also put into a `@PathVariable` but in my scenario the value doesn't matter. If you configure a path variable you need to give it a default because the pattern will only be satisfied depending on the value of your URL.

The regex tells Spring Boot only to react if the url doesn't contain `webjars` or `actuator`. The regex itself is best explained by using regex101:

[image]